# Blending/smooth-shading material

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating and drawing a triangle mesh in wpf c# using `GeometryModel3D`. I've been trying to figure out how to create a smooth shading over the triangles, like the classic openGL smooth shaded triangle.

I would like to define a colour for each vertex, and then having the colours interpolated over the face, like this, assuming the three colour where red, green and blue.

[image]

I assumed I would need to use a brush, but I haven't been able to figure out how.
So any help would be appreciated, or any pointer to a guide that shows me how to achieve this.

**EDIT:**
I've looked at [Triangular Gradient in WPF3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653489/triangular-gradient-in-wpf3d), which seems to answer the question partly, just using xaml.
Unfortunatly it seems like it need equilateral triangles.

**2nd EDIT**
The answer above, uses the `RadialGradientBrush`. Is the `RadiusX`and `RadiusY` used to make it elliptic instead of circular?

**3rd EDIT**
Okay, I'm fairly sure I can use the `RadialGradientBrush`. What I think I can do is, find the center of the circumcircle of the triangles, and create a `RadialGradientBrush` with `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` equal to the radius if the circumcircle. I would then move the focal point of the `RadialGradientBrush` to the vertices with `GradientOrigin`.

`GradientOrigin` takes two doubles X,Y as the center, with both of them being in the interval [0,1]. From what I can read is X = 0.0 is the left side and X = 1.0 is the right side and Y = 0.0 is the top and Y = 1.0 is the bottom. What I can't figure out, is this mapping [0,1]x[0,1] to a circle, or is it a square? The mapping from the vertices of the triangle to [0,1]x[0,1], depends on what shape this interval represents.

Comment: In WPF the origin and offset of brush objects maps to the rectangle needed to completely contain the geometry.  X=0 and Y=0 is the upper-left corner of this rectangle, while X=1 and Y=1 is the lower-right corner.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [Helix 3D Toolkit](https://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/) for WPF ?

I didn't go as far as you'd like but I guess it is possible by looking at the *[Surface Demo](https://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SurfaceDemo)* example :

[image]

Comment: Yes this seems like something in the right direction. Unfortunatly I don't think I can translate the helix3d toolkit code, to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

There are surely libraries for that, but to give some simple way, searching through some google,http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-triangle-or-not/

computing the distance from corners, gives info about the smooth color. Checking if point is in triangle.

```
float area(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3)
        {
            return (float)Math.Abs((x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y1) + x3 * (y1 - y2)) / 2.0);
        }

        bool isInside(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x, int y)
        {
            /* Calculate area of triangle ABC */
            float A = area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);

            /* Calculate area of triangle PBC */
            float A1 = area(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3);

            /* Calculate area of triangle PAC */
            float A2 = area(x1, y1, x, y, x3, y3);

            /* Calculate area of triangle PAB */
            float A3 = area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y);

            /* Check if sum of A1, A2 and A3 is same as A */
            return (A == A1 + A2 + A3);
        }


 for (int ii = 5; ii < 100; ii++)
          {
               for (int jj = 5; jj < 100; jj++)
                {
                        int distanceRed =0, distanceGreen =0,distanceBlue =0;
                        if (isInside(30, 50, 30, 90, 20, 70, ii, jj))
                        {
                              distanceRed = (int)Math.Sqrt(((ii - 30) * (ii - 30) + (jj - 50) * (jj - 50)));
                              distanceGreen = (int)Math.Sqrt(((ii - 30) * (ii - 30) + (jj - 90) * (jj - 90)));
                              distanceBlue = (int)Math.Sqrt(((ii - 20) * (ii - 20) + (jj - 70) * (jj - 70)));
                          }
                          else
                          {
                               distanceRed = 0; distanceGreen = 0; distanceBlue = 0;
                          }

                              ptr[(((int)jj) * 3) + ((int)ii) * stride] = (byte)(distanceRed % 256);
                              ptr[(((int)jj) * 3) + ((int)ii) * stride + 1] = (byte)(distanceGreen % 256);
                              ptr[(((int)jj) * 3) + ((int)ii) * stride + 2] = (byte)(distanceBlue % 256);

                           }
                       }
```

gives the result:

[image]

Couldnt fit the red. Maybe the modulo is wrong here.
Also the sqrt is inefficient.